Calculate proof size of a function that reads state
How would one calculate the proof size of a storage read?
To give some more context. In our chain extension we have certain functions that do a storage read from the runtime. Now atm we charge weight with env.charge_weight(T::DbWeight::get().reads(1_u64))?;. This however doesn't include the proof size, how do I do this?

The Proof size weight of a storage read is the maximal size of the storage item being read. We have the MaxEncodedLen trait to track this. So you need contextual information about the type that is being read and then use MaxEncodedLen::max_encoded_len() on it.
Depending on what the chain extension does, it may or may not be easily possible to know what key is being accessed. Smart contracts are normally uses an optimistic approach and revert on error, whereas FRAME requires to know the worst case effort in advance. These are just fundamentally different computational models.
If you can: write a benchmark. The only way to currently write FRAME benchmarks it to use a pallet; for example the minimal pallet or some mocked types just to make the benchmark compile.
If you want to know how to charge it exactly, that would be env.charge_weight(Weight::from_parts(0, proof_size)).
